# error:key does not contain a section global - ardupilot, github, building pixhawk, arduplane

Tags: git, bash

I have used GitHub desktop, git bash and px4 console previously to clone files to a pixhawk as in http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/building-px4-with-make.html. It has worked.

I logged in today and have changed code in two of the files within arduplane and when I go to Git Bash to set up the build onto pixhawk by typing '`git config global core.arducrlf false`' I get the following error:

```
key does not contain a section global
```

I have not had this error previously and I haven't changed any git files per se - as it seems to be implied in similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it should be:

```
git config --global core.arducrlf false
```

That is assuming `arducrlf` is a special value for this project.
If not, it might be:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

In both instances, you need `--global`, not `global`.

Comment: @GeorgiCarpenter No problem. You can see more at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config---global